# Recover Pictures

Tags: internal-storage, 5.1-lollipop, broken-screen

Ok, so I just dropped my android 5.1 Moto G. the screen is unresponsive and has lines and squares running along it.

I was wondering if there was any way to recover photos from this phone, as it works, but when I connect to the computer it is locked, and, as the screen is unresponsive, I cant unlock it.

Thanks, Josh

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! I warmly recommend you to start with our [broken-screen tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info). As you're not the first one here with this issue (not the second either ;) we've setup some first-aid there. You can find a data recovery section at the end of that page. Good luck!

Comment: Did you have USB Debugging enabled prior to losing functionality of the touch screen? Alternatively, do you have a USB OTG cable on hand?

Answer (score 0):

Get an OTG cable and connect it with your phone. Unlock it. Install Vysor for future use. Download something like solid explorer and copy everything to SDCard. Now remove the card and transfer it to your PC/Laptop.